# How to use Powershell 2 Get-WmiObject to find an instance of SQL Server Reporting Services (SQL2008) on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, sql, wmi, ssrs

I'm trying to use the powershell 2 "Get-WmiObject" command to find the reporting service instance using this command

```
 get-wmiobject -class "MSReportServer_Instance" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer"
```

### THE ERROR I GET BACK

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class
At line:1 char:14
+ get-wmiobject <<<<  -class "MSReportServer_Instance" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

### NOTES

- This is Powershell 2
- OS = Windows Server 2008 R2 RC (x64)
- SQL = SQL 2008 SP1 (x64)
- Reporting Services is installed and works - have several reports running)
- Everything is running on the same box (the script, SQL, SSRS)
- Link to WMI info for SSRS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152858.aspx
- I've tried (guessing) different variations on the namespace but nothing worked

### THE ANSWER (2009-06-22)

The code below finds the instance and places it into *$rs_instance*

```
$ns = Get-WmiObject -class "__NAMESPACE" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer"
$rs_instance_name = "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\" + $ns.Name + "\v10"
$rs_instance = Get-WmiObject -class "MSReportServer_Instance" -namespace $rs_instance_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [WmiExplorer.ps1](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/03/22/powershell-wmi-explorer-part-1.aspx) script I can see the instance name in __NAMESPACE and this query returns my instance name:

```
gwmi -class "__NAMESPACE" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer"
```

To get to MSReporterServer_Instance you must supply the instance name in this example my instance name is RS_SQL2K8:

```
gwmi -class "MSReportServer_Instance" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_SQL2K8\v10"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, is it a valid class?

Try this:
PS>get-wmiobject -list -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer"

Does that class get listed?

Shortcut:
PS>get-wmiobject -list -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer"|where{$_.name -eq "MSReportServer_Instance"}

I have a VM running Server 2008 with SQL 2008 and can try this out tomorrow.

If you're not sure of the namespace:
PS> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root" -Class "__NAMESPACE" | Format-List Name

(That's from: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31024041&threadid=31024027)

Comment: Actually, as per that link you provided, your namespace needs to look like this:
root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\<InstanceName>\v10 

This works from a Microsoft VM:
PS> get-wmiobject -class "MSReportServer_Instance" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\rs_mssqlserver\v10"

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do requires WMI this may be missing the point, but SQL Server 2008 ships with managed extensions that means most automation tasks no longer need to be perfromed with WMI.

For example on a machine with the client extensions installed either select the DB with **open in powershell** right click context menu command *or* **load the extensions** in any powershell session (http://blogs.msdn.com/mwories/archive/2008/06/14/SQL2008_5F00_Powershell.aspx) and you can do the following:

```
PS > cd SQLSERVER
PS > Set-Location \sql\MyServer\ReportServer
```

You can now manage the database objects just like you would manipulate your locla file system in PowerShell (for example try running dir . | Get-Member to see some properties to interact with).